# Launcher activity's onResume() method gets called twice but onCreate() only once

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

When my app starts, the launcher activity's onCreate() method gets called normally only once. But that is immediately followed by two calls to onResume(). When I inspect the code, both instances are of the same class but only one has instanced members from the onCreate(), obviously.

Everything is working fine, though. I am just curious trying to understand why this is happening. Does anybody have any ideas? I'm using SherlockFragmentActivity, does that have anything to do with it? I'm happy to provide more information as needed. I just don't know now what else is relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: is onResume method called twice each time or only some times its called twice. my concern is that is it getting called twice due to orientation changes from landscape to portarait or vice versa

Comment: It is called twice every time I start the app for the first time and on orientation changes. I tested it a few times now and onResume() was called twice every time but onCreate() only once.